# debian wheezy console application set font size

Tags: python, debian, raspberry-pi

How do I set font size for Python console application?

I'm running `Debian Wheezy` on a Raspberry Pi.

When the program is exited return to default size.

Answer (score 0):

you can not do this. 
font size is determined by terminal emulator not program output.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`setfont`](http://www.perpetualpc.net/srtd_setfont.html) command :

```
$ setfont CyrAsia-Terminus24x12
```

a list of fonts is available in: `/usr/share/consolefonts`.
In addition to that you can  run `dpkg-reconfigure -plow console-setup` to tweak various console settings .

Comment: So I can put this line inside my Python program? What is the $ for?

Comment: i put the "$" sign to indicate that the command should be run from the console.